# Reasons behind selective filtering of immigrants by India

Tags: india, illegal-immigration, refugees, secularism

The president of the ruling party (BJP) promised during election campaigning that [only refugees belonging to Hindu, Sikh and Buddha will be allowed into India](https://scroll.in/latest/919700/bjp-will-implement-nrc-across-the-country-amit-shah-reiterates-in-west-bengal). The government also seems to be thinking along the same lines. Since [India is a secular country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secularism_in_India), can this discrimination among religious lines be acceptable? What are the political implications of this statement?

Comment: The news article talks of refugees, not immigrants.

Comment: Acceptable to whom? It's obviously acceptable to those proposing it. And there are shades of secularism https://www.outlookindia.com/website/story/why-india-is-not-a-secular-state/239584 This not a new debate https://www.jstor.org/stable/24457469

Comment: and flares up once in a while https://www.bloombergquint.com/opinion/how-indias-laws-made-it-a-hindu-secular-state For a more global take on the issue see https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/government/2019/02/05/modis-india-erdogans-turkey-and-the-crisis-of-the-secular-state-in-the-non-western-world/

Comment: Related question here https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/37909/legal-basis-of-religion-for-citizenship-amendment-bill